# Creating JSON structure using Path values in JAVA

Tags: java, json

I have an array which contains path values as shown below:

```
{"A/B1","A/B2","B2/C3","B2/C4"}
```

I want to create a json structure using this which should look like:

```
[
  {
    label : A,
    child : [
      {label : 'B1'},
      {label : 'B2',
       child : [
         {label : 'C3'},{label : 'C4'}
       ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to do something like below:

```
package com.ds.test;

import java.util.Iterator;  
import java.util.Map;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class Test {

    private static String pathArray[] = {"A/B1","A/B2","B2/C3","B2/C4"};
    private static JSONArray resultJson = null;

    private static void buildJson(String pathStr) throws JSONException{
        String elems[] = pathStr.split("/");
        String parent = "";
        for(int jj = 0; jj < elems.length; jj++){
            checkAndAdd(elems[jj],parent);
            parent = elems[jj];
        }

    }

    private static void checkAndAdd(String elem,String parent) throws JSONException{
        if(parent.isEmpty()){
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("label",elem );
            resultJson.put(obj);
        }
        else{
            for(int jj = 0; jj < resultJson.length(); jj++){
                //to do;
                //if json element contains element with label = parent then add elem as child
                //to it.
            }
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        resultJson = new JSONArray();

        for(int ii=0; ii < pathArray.length; ii++){
            buildJson(pathArray[ii]);
        }
    }

    }
```

But, I am not getting a way by which I can check if an element is already present so that I can add child array to it. I want to do it recursively, but not getting a way.

Can someone suggest me a way by which I can proceed? I am not asking for complete code help. I just need some logic to proceed? Can someone help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it as a graph problem or a tree problem. All you need to do is create a Graph or Tree with following vertices

A  B2 B2  C3 C4.

Add correct edges to it. So now you have something like this

```
       A
     /   \
   B1     B2
  /    \  / \ 
 C1   C2  C3  C4
```

Now you just have to BFS or Level order traversal.